# Why are co- and contravariance (out, in) only allowed on interfaces and delegates?

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, out, contravariance

I know how to use and the meaning of `out` and `in`.
But why can we not use it on regular generic type class and give the class same ablility like this:

```
public class Some<out T>
{
}
Some<Derived> a = new Some<Derived>();
Some<Base> b = a;
```

Comment: The answer link above is a duplicate as well.